# How to get javascript to ignore a known missing element

Tags: javascript, error-handling, element

I am writing a script and I would like to know how to elegantly tell JS not to care if an element is missing and certainly don't error on it, especially if they are known unknown.

**The premise:** Create an autonotify script if the state liquor store has stock in of the liquors I specify (buffalo trace looking at you). The official liquor site (VABC) does not have this feature.

The website always displays your Favorite Store (hardcoded) but it will only show the 5 next stores *if they have stock in*. If you are on the product page of the liquor you want, and stores around you have stock, they will be shown. But if only 3 stores have stock, only 3 will be shown. If none around you have stock, then none are shown. The problem is that I have no idea which products (I am searching for several) or which stores (again, favorite+5) will have stock. So I have to declare the same set of variables each time.

If say a Product does not have Stores 3-5, I want Javascript to be able to just move on. Right now I am getting an error of '**Error: Can't call getText on element with selector "(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[2]" because element wasn't found'**. The script is expecting Store 2 (aka the 'Miles) to be present, but since there's no stock, no store is present on this page.

I tried hiding this Store2Miles.getText() call behind an IsExisting = True gate, but the system still throws this error. The result is script/site just sits there and waits to Timeout. Since it does this on several pages, this makes the script run much longer then it should. Like I said, I want an elegant solution.

Code:

```
    it(Product1, ()=> {
        browser.url(Product1_URL)
        console.log(Product1)

        let MoreStores = $("(//a[contains(@class,'more-stores')])[1]")
        MoreStores.waitForClickable(500)
        MoreStores.click()

        /*
This section contains the amount of product at my favorite store, and the Address, Miles, and 
        Amount of each of the 5 stores. Since I have no idea how much stock will be of each product, I 
        have to send this complete set to all product pages.
*/

        let MyStoreAmount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[1]")
        let Store2Address = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Store')])[2]")
        let Store2Miles = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[2]")
        let Store2Amount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[2]")
        let Store3Address = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Store')])[3]") 
        let Store3Miles = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[3]")
        let Store3Amount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[3]")
        let Store4Address = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Store')])[4]") 
        let Store4Miles = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[4]")
        let Store4Amount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[4]")
        let Store5Address = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Store')])[5]") 
        let Store5Miles = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[5]")
        let Store5Amount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[5]")
        let Store6Address = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Store')])[6]") 
        let Store6Miles = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Miles')])[6]")
        let Store6Amount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[6]")

        /*
This section is me creating boolean variables of if Stores are Existing (meaning they have 
        stock) and if they are Nearby. I only care about stores that are stocked and close to me. A 
         stocked store 100 miles away is useless, as is a local store that is empty. I am trying to do 
        IsExisting flags first so that the getText() code wouldn't be read (and thus error) if the store 
        didn't exist first. */

        let MyStoreStocked = false
        let Store2Existing = false
        let Store3Existing = false
        let Store4Existing = false
        let Store5Existing = false
        let Store6Existing = false

        let Store2Nearby = false
        let Store3Nearby = false
        let Store4Nearby = false
        let Store5Nearby = false
        let Store6Nearby = false

        /*
This creates a T/F flag of if your store is stocked with the product you specified
*/
        if (MyStoreAmount.getText() > 0){MyStoreStocked = true} else {MyStoreStocked = false}
        

        /*
This creates T/F flag of if your store exists on the product page. If it doesn't exist, then it 
        has 0 stock. However just because it exists doesn't mean it's close by, it could be 300 miles 
        away.*/

        if (Store2Address.isExisting()){Store2Existing = true} else{Store2Existing = false}
        if (Store3Address.isExisting()){Store3Existing = true} else{Store3Existing = false}
        if (Store4Address.isExisting()){Store4Existing = true} else{Store4Existing = false}
        if (Store5Address.isExisting()){Store5Existing = true} else{Store5Existing = false}
        if (Store6Address.isExisting()){Store6Existing = true} else{Store6Existing = false}
        
        
        /*
I know due to Debugging that this is the exact spot that errors occur.** The first line, the 
        Store2Miles.getText(), even though I tried hiding it behind an If isExisting=True, the system 
        always throws an error on it. It is saying that this element wasn't found. I KNOW some of these 
        won't be found, that's why I put the isExisting gate there. But the system still reads it 
        anyways, and timesout. These timeouts make the whole script run longer. 
]*/

        if (Store2Existing = true){if (Store2Miles.getText() <= Product1_Distance) {Store2Nearby = true} else {Store2Nearby = false}} else {}
        if (Store3Existing = true){if (Store3Miles.getText() <= Product1_Distance) {Store3Nearby = true} else {Store3Nearby = false}} else {}
        if (Store4Existing = true){if (Store4Miles.getText() <= Product1_Distance) {Store4Nearby = true} else {Store4Nearby = false}} else {}
        if (Store5Existing = true){if (Store5Miles.getText() <= Product1_Distance) {Store5Nearby = true} else {Store5Nearby = false}} else {}
        if (Store6Existing = true){if (Store6Miles.getText() <= Product1_Distance) {Store6Nearby = true} else {Store6Nearby = false}} else {}
```

Comment: First inclination would be to put your store Element objects into an array. That will allow you to use `.filter()` and iterators. Additionally, you might consider using a generator function that only `yields` under the correct condition. Alternatively, not recommended, you could use `try/catch` block and swallow the error.

Comment: A simple approach is to just test your variable after the query, but before you attempt to access it. For example, after doing `let MyStoreAmount = $("(//td[contains(@data-title,'Inventory')])[1]")`, you could just then do `if(MyStoreAmount){...}`, which will check for it existence. If it exists, use it, if not, move on.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What filter would I use? Thus far is seems like a catch-22. For me to see if it exists, it causes an error. But how can I not use it unless I know it doesn't exist?

Comment: @ScottMarcus See my comment above. I keep using IsExisting to check for existence, but system still throws an error saying that it doesn't exist.

Comment: After looking at it, I determined using filter was not necessary. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking terms of an object containing a name, distance and quantity. Collecting all your data allows easier conditional tests.

Here each store is collected into a set of objects, but the store is only included if it exists in the DOM. The `isNearby` property is calculated at the time of creation.

In the HTML stores 2 & 3 are lacking content and only store 1 is considered near by.

Note: You'll have to put your XPATH back into this code. (I was too lazy to spin up a project)

```js
const Product1_Distance = 25;
const storeCount = 4;
const stores = $("td[data-title^=Store]");
const miles = $("td[data-title^=Miles]");
const amounts = $("td[data-title^=Inventory]");
const collection = [];
for (let i = 0; i < storeCount; i++) {
  const store = stores[i].textContent;
  const dist = miles[i].textContent;
  const qty = amounts[i].textContent;
  if (store && dist && qty) {
    const isNearby = dist <= Product1_Distance;
    collection.push({ store, dist, qty, isNearby });
  }
}

for (let store of collection) {
  console.log(store);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Store">Store1</td>
        <td data-title="Inventory">26</td>
        <td data-title="Miles">12</td>
        <td data-title="Store">Store2</td>
        <td data-title="Inventory">2</td>
        <td data-title="Miles"></td>
        <td data-title="Store"></td>
        <td data-title="Inventory">260</td>
        <td data-title="Miles">18</td>
        <td data-title="Store">Store4</td>
        <td data-title="Inventory">2</td>
        <td data-title="Miles">90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually very new to javascript. I did visual basic back in HS/College, but that was 20 years ago. I'll take a look at your code over the next few days and try to understand all of the components. Then try to integrate into my existing code.

Comment: While not to take away from what @Randy Casburn said, what I eventually ended up doing was putting each segment of code I knew had the possibility of failure into a Try/Catch. This was then inserted into a List, with the Break List being the Catch condition. So when the StoreX is eventually not found, this error will be handled by the Catch, and it will also Break the list. Meaning all processing will stop and the code will move out of the List.

Comment: <!-- begin snippet:  -->
<!-- language: lang-js -->

  list: {
    try{
        if(Store2Miles.getText() < c)
        {console.log('Store2 exists and is near'),
        Store2Nearby = true}
        else {console.log('Store2 exists and is NOT near'),
        Store2Nearby = false}
        }
        catch (err) {
         console.log('Store2 does not exist')
         Store2Nearby = false
         Store3Nearby = false
         Store4Nearby = false
         Store5Nearby = false
         Store6Nearby = false
        break list
        }
<!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 0):

While not to take away from what @Randy Casburn said, what I eventually ended up doing was putting each segment of code I knew had the possibility of failure into a Try/Catch. This was then inserted into a List, with the Break List being the Catch condition. So when the StoreX is eventually not found, this error will be handled by the Catch, and it will also Break the list. Meaning all processing will stop and the code will move out of the List.

````
   list: {
    try{
        if(Store2Miles.getText() < c)
        {console.log('Store2 exists and is near'),
        Store2Nearby = true}
        else {console.log('Store2 exists and is NOT near'),
        Store2Nearby = false}
        }
        catch (err) {
         console.log('Store2 does not exist')
         Store2Nearby = false
         Store3Nearby = false
         Store4Nearby = false
         Store5Nearby = false
         Store6Nearby = false
        break list
        }  
    ```
````